# How can I determine what causes a mystery window to be created?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, window, desktop-environments

I have what appears to be a window which is always created in my desktop environment:

[image: full desktop]

[image: closeup]

See that white bar in the upper left corner? It seems to be a 5x1 pixel window. I can drag it around. Right click does nothing. It is always present and on all desktops.

In the screenshots I am using i3 window manager, but the window is also present when I use x fce4 (via Xubuntu, the distro installed on this system).

Is there a way to determine what is creating that window and or kill it?

## Cause found:

Found the culprit thanks to answers. It was `ibus-ui-gtk3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**xwininfo** (just start it and click on the window with the cross icon that appears) can tell you some details of that window and **xkill** can get rid of it.
Unfortunately, the starter script system of ANY window manager is a stack of spaghetti and whenever attempts to simplify are made it's even more spaghettified so I don't dare to give hints without seeing.
Once you have info about the window, you may have some clue what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using wmctrl to list all the windows with the pids that own them

```
$ wmctrl -lp
0x02400001  0 5384   bagend TweetDeck - Google Chrome
0x01e00023  0 5331   bagend linux - How can I determine what causes a mystery window to be created? - Super User - Mozilla Firefox
```

This will list all the current windows being managed by the window manager. The third field is the pid of the process owning the window

Comment: Nothing strange appears there. Maybe I'm wrong in assuming it's a window.